# What is `AnyType` in java generics

Tags: java

What is `AnyType` in java. When should i use it.
For example `TestRpn<AnyType extends Comparable<AnyType>>` in this code snippet what is `AnyType`, and what kind of data it can have (i.e, like Integer,Boolean)

Comment: it is literally any type ;)

Comment: What did you research prior to asking this question? I am fairly sure your search engine could have found the answer faster than you got it here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no predefined type named `AnyType`. I am guessing you have come across a poorly named type parameter variable. The naming convention for type variables is [suggested to be single uppercase letters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html), to avoid this type of confusion.

In your case, `TestRpn<AnyType extends Comparable<AnyType>>` should be rephrased as `TestRpn<E extends Comparable<E>>`, which in turn means that you can substitute any type for E that implements Comparable for it's own type. Example: java.lang.String implements `Comparable<String>`, so `TestRpn<String>` is a valid parametrization of the above base type.

Comment: @PieterDeBie most of the time, yes. There are valid counter-examples, e.g. a method that converts one map to another by processing a function on the values. Such a method would have the type parameters K, V1 and V2.

Comment: Indeed. And to be honest, I'm not that fond of the convention. Sometimes I have short type names that are way more understandable.

Answer (score 3):

AnyType is actually used in java7+. It can be said that its usage is same as that of  E or T or something. As the name suggests it can any type of generic data.
for example, when I implemented my generic linked list in Java, I used

```
private Node<AnyType> head;
```

where the word AnyType stands for the generic type Node.